# ¿Me podéis decir dónde está el error?

Tags: java, poo, condiciones

Estoy aprendiendo el lenguaje Java y realizando algunos ejercicios, en uno de ellos me he encontrado con un error que no puedo deducir porque se trata.
Es a la hora de realizar bucles if. Se que la solución del ejercicio podría darse de alguna manera más óptima, pero en el momento en el que me encuentro del curso, sólo puedo utilizar bucles if.

La cosa es que al meter un número negativo, se ejecuta la orden para convertirlo en positivo, pero no sigue leyendo código como lo haría si meto un número positivo de tres cifras.
Se como se soluciona el problema (utilizando una solución diferente), pero entre las diferentes formas que probé, en esta que os voy a indicar, me encontré con el problema que arriba os indico.
Me gustaría saber porque ocurre lo que ocurre.

```
    package com.mycompany.e19_cuantos_digitos;
    import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author davidpozocatalina
 * 
 * Realiza un programa que nos diga cuántos dígitos tiene un número entero que puede 
 * ser positivo o negativo. Se permiten números de hasta 5 dígitos.
 * 
 */

public class CuantosDigitos {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        int numAbsoluto;
        int digitos = 0;
        
        System.out.println("¿Cuántos dígitos tiene el número introducido?");
        System.out.println("Máximo cinco cifras y puede ser positivo o negativo");
        System.out.println("Introduce el número: ");
        num = s.nextInt();
        
        
        int cociente;
        int cifras = 0;
        
        cociente = num;

        if (num == 0){
            System.out.println("¡El 0 no es un número!");
        }
        
        if (num < 0){
            cociente = -num;
            System.out.println("Comprobando si se ha convertido en positivo: " + 
            cociente);
        }
        
        if (num >= 100000){
            System.out.println("Sólo números de como máximo cinco cifras");
        }
        
        cociente = cociente / 10;
        cifras++;
        
        //System.out.println("Al dividir un entero entre diez, aparece así: " + 
        cociente);      //--> Para comprobar si se convertía en float o double.
        
        if (cociente == 0){
            System.out.println("El número " + num + " tiene " + cifras + " cifras.");
        } else {
            cociente = cociente / 10;
            cifras++;
        }
        
        if (cociente == 0){
            System.out.println("El número " + num + " tiene " + cifras + " cifras.");
        } else {
            cociente = cociente / 10;
            cifras++;
        }
        
        if (cociente == 0){
            System.out.println("El número " + num + " tiene " + cifras + " cifras.");
        } else {
            cociente = cociente / 10;
            cifras++;
        }
        
        if (cociente == 0){
            System.out.println("El número " + num + " tiene " + cifras + " cifras.");
        } else {
            cociente = cociente / 10;
            cifras++;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Gracias. Un saludo.

- Al poner un número negativo, sólo se ejecuta el bucle if que dice comprobando si se ha convertido en positivo, pero luego no se ejecutan los demás if, a ese problema me refiero. No entiendo porque se para ahí el código.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio , agrega ejemplo de que es lo ingresas y obtienes y que es lo que desearías se mostrará y porque razón, no es muy entendible lo que intentas realizar, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: error eliminar cociente); linea 52 ????? cociente);

    agregar codigo if para numero negativo de mas de 5 cifras no esta previsto

        Sin ese error funciona ¿Cuántos dígitos tiene el número introducido? Máximo cinco cifras y puede ser positivo o negativo Introduce el número: -1000 Comprobando si se ha convertido en positivo: 1000 El número -1000 tiene 4 cifras.

Answer (score 0):

¿Cuál es el error que te daría?

Tu código lo que hace es validar el número de cifras que tiene el número introducido. Si metes (por ejemplo) 1000:
¿Cuántos dígitos tiene el número introducido?
Máximo cinco cifras y puede ser positivo o negativo
Introduce el número:
1000
Al dividir un entero entre diez, aparece así: 100
El número 1000 tiene 4 cifras.

Si por el contrario, metes -1000:
Introduce el número:
-1000
Comprobando si se ha convertido en positivo: 1000
Al dividir un entero entre diez, aparece así: 100
El número -1000 tiene 4 cifras.

Ahora bien, si el número introducido es negativo y tiene más de 5 cifras verás que no te muestra nada:
-100000
Comprobando si se ha convertido en positivo: 100000
Al dividir un entero entre diez, aparece así: 10000

Porque el control que metes solo es para números positivos (no negativos de más de 5 dígitos). De hecho esa misma validación está mal porque no controlas los 5 dígitos si no 6: if (num >= 100000)

Lo dicho, ¿Qué error te da?

Comment: Pero al convertir por ejemplo -200000 a positivo, el siguiente if me tendría que decir que es un número mayor de cinco cifras, ¿no?

Comment: Nop, porque estás validando la variable num (que es la que introduces por teclado):  if (num >= 100000) y no la variable cociente que es la que transformas en positivo. :)

Comment: Vale. Joder, que torpe soy. Gracias!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, un ***bucle*** es un ***ciclo*** y lo que tu tienes son ***sentencias*** `if`, no bucles `if`.
El código que compartes funciona como debería `if (cociente == 0)` evalúa si `cociente` vale **cero** y, si y solo si `cociente` vale **cero** se ejecutará el contenido de la sentencia `if`.
El código termina porque no está en bucle, no hay ninguna instrucción que indique que debe de hacer después de convertir el numero a positivo y no tiene errores de sintaxis o de ejecución.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Veo que estaba equivocado y que al meter un número negativo de como máximo cinco cifras si que me dice los dígitos que tiene. Pero al meter un número mayor de cinco cifras y negativo, sólo me lo convierte en positivo pero no me dice nada más, estando el condicional más adelante de la conversión a positivo, no entiendo porque no me sale el aviso de que es mayor de cinco cifras.

Answer (score 0):

if es una concicional no un bucle

```
package com.mycompany.e19_cuantos_digitos;
    import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author davidpozocatalina
 * 
 * Realiza un programa que nos diga cuántos dígitos tiene un número entero que puede 
 * ser positivo o negativo. Se permiten números de hasta 5 dígitos.
 * 
 */

public class CuantosDigitos {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        int numAbsoluto;
        int digitos = 0;
        
        System.out.println("¿Cuántos dígitos tiene el número introducido?");
        System.out.println("Máximo cinco cifras y puede ser positivo o negativo");
        System.out.println("Introduce el número: ");
        num = s.nextInt();
        
        
        int cociente;
        int cifras = 0;
        
        cociente = num;

        if (num == 0){
            System.out.println("¡El 0 no es un número!");
        }else if(num < 0 ){
            cociente = -num;
        }
//debes asegurar que este mensaje solo aparezca si se introduce un negativo y el que se valida es cociente 
        if(cociente<100000&&num<0){
            System.out.println("Comprobando si se ha convertido en positivo: " + cociente);
        }else if (cociente >= 100000){
            System.out.println("Sólo números de como máximo cinco cifras");
        }
        
         System.out.println(""); 

        cociente = cociente / 10;
        cifras++;
        
        if (cociente == 0){
            System.out.println("El número " + num + " tiene " + cifras + " cifras.");
        } else {
            cociente = cociente / 10;
            cifras++;
        }
        

       if (cociente == 0){
            System.out.println("El número " + num + " tiene " + cifras + " cifras.");
        } else {
            cociente = cociente / 10;
            cifras++;
        }
        


        if (cociente == 0){
            System.out.println("El número " + num + " tiene " + cifras + " cifras.");
        } else {
            cociente = cociente / 10;
            cifras++;
        }
        
        if (cociente == 0){
            System.out.println("El número " + num + " tiene " + cifras + " cifras.");
        } else {
            cociente = cociente / 10;
            cifras++;
        }
        
        if (cociente == 0){
            System.out.println("El número " + num + " tiene " + cifras + " cifras.");
        } else {
            cociente = cociente / 10;
            cifras++;
        }



    }
    
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Veo que estaba equivocado y que al meter un número negativo de como máximo cinco cifras si que me dice los dígitos que tiene. Pero al meter un número mayor de cinco cifras y negativo, sólo me lo convierte en positivo pero no me dice nada más, estando el condicional más adelante de la conversión a positivo, no entiendo porque no me sale el aviso de que es mayor de cinco cifras.

Comment: la condicion que le pones para que salga ese mensaje es if (num >= 100000) pero esto nunca se va a ejecutar con un numero negativo mayor de 5 cifras xk num es negativo en vez de num debiste evaluar if(cociente>=100000) xk cociente es =-num lo cual lo convierte en positivo cumpliendo la condicion que arroja el mensaje "Sólo números de como máximo cinco cifras"

Comment: Vale, muchísimas gracias!!